# Simple Disabling of JPanels in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, boolean, boolean-logic

So I have been trying to disable/enable a jPanel within a jTabbedPane (on Netbeans) using a simple boolean and the boolean always gets stuck on false.  The disabling/enabling of the jPanel within the jTabbedPane is triggered by the click of a button.  Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
package programming.club;

/**
 *
 * @author RandomGuy
 */

public class GranadaProgrammingClubUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static boolean allowNavigation = true;



/**
 * Creates new form ProgrammingClubUI
 */
public ProgrammingClubUI() {
    initComponents();
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        if (allowNavigation == false) {
             jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, true);
            allowNavigation = true;
         }
        if (allowNavigation == true) {
            jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, false);
            allowNavigation = false;
         }

         System.out.println(allowNavigation);

    }
```

I put the System.out.println(allowNavigation); just to check what the value of allowNavigation was, and every time I click the button, the value just stays as false, but it should be switching, and changing the status of the jPanel, enabled or disabled! (I think)  I really can't figure out what's wrong here.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: `static` is not your friend, beware.  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: also allowNavigation == true is not necessary use (allowNavigation) instead

Comment: Thanks, MadProgrammer, I should have caught that `static`, it was just a habit after doing it so much in other programs.  Also, I knew about that shortcut, madhawa priyashantha.  I had just changed it to make sure it wasn't causing some sort of problem.  Thanks again, guys!

Comment: @agillgilla and i think you should if else not two if because both conditions can true

Comment: Tip: Be sure to add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* a person of a new comment.  Only one person can be notified per comment.

Comment: If the above suggestions have not lead you to solve your problem, then consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explaining your problem in greater detail, including just what sort of behavior you are expecting vs what you're getting.

Comment: Actually, I removed the `static` and it still does the same thing.  Unchanging.  Got any ideas, @MadProgrammer?

Comment: Yes I do. Please see my comment above!

Comment: Nevermind, just messed up the if statement, @MadProgrammer.  Thanks for the tip, madhawa priyashantha

Comment: @agillgilla SEE MY ANSWER USE IF ELSE NOT IF IF BECAUSE IF IF ISNOT CORRECT FOR YOUR LOGIC SEE IF allowNavigation FALSE IT WILL EXCUTE CODE INSIDE YOUR FIRST IF BLOCK AND MAKE allowNavigation TO TRUE AND JUST GO TO 2ND IF AND MAKE IT FALSE

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha NO NEED TO YELL... ;)

Comment: You were right, @madhawapriyashantha, the `if else` was necessary for the boolean not to just change back right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think problem is

```
if (allowNavigation == false) {
     jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, true);
    allowNavigation = true;
 }
if (allowNavigation == true) {
    jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, false);
    allowNavigation = false;
 }
```

you should use

```
     if (allowNavigation == false) {
         jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, true);
        allowNavigation = true;
     }
    else if (allowNavigation == true) {
        jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, false);
        allowNavigation = false;
     }
```

because if allownavigation false it will go to first if and make it true and then go to second if and make it false

and also good boolean check is

```
if (!allowNavigation) {
     jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, true);
    allowNavigation = true;
 }
else if (allowNavigation) {
    jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, false);
    allowNavigation = false;
 }
```

Comment: Took a bit to understand the difference, but I'd agree with that assessment... +1

Comment: FYI that logic can be reduced down to just 2 lines: (1) `allowNavigation = !allowNavigation;` and then (2) `jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, allowNavigation);`